# How to speed up list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Below is my list:

```
col = [['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow'],
       ['pink', 'orange', 'brown', 'pink', 'brown']
      ]
```

My goal is to eliminate items that appear once in each list.

Here is my code:

```
eliminate = [[w for w in c if c.count(w)>1]for c in col]

Output: [['red', 'red', 'yellow','yellow'], ['pink','pink', 'brown','brown']]
```

The code works fine for small dataset such as the list above, however, my dataset is very large. Each list contains up to a 1000 items.

Is there a way to make the above code work faster? like breaking the code down into two or more for-loops, as my understanding is that the normal for-loop is faster than list comprehension.

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Hi Martijin, thanks for your response. Then problem is about speed (complexity) not the duplication.

Comment: order is not important

Comment: In all cases I've measured the time a list comprehension was always faster than a standard for loop. You might be able to speed up this by generating a counter of the list items outside of the loop.

Comment: yes, items with more than one elements. The code in the question could resolve that, but the efficiency in terms of speed matters a lot given the size of my data.

Comment: Matthias, you seem to be making a good point, but do it let see.

Comment: Hi all, I just updated the question, there was mistake in the output I wrote initially. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters possibly even `['red', 'red', 'red']` given the updated example if it's now indeed correct, but the OPs gone somewhat silent...

Comment: @Tiger1: Updated my answer too then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python sum of non duplicate int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172765/python-sum-of-non-duplicate-int)

Answer (score 9):

I'd have a go at trying an `OrderedCounter` to avoid the repeated `.count()` calls:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

col=[['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow'],['pink', 'orange', 'brown', 'pink', 'brown']]

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

new = [[k for k, v in OrderedCounter(el).iteritems() if v != 1] for el in col]
# [['red', 'yellow'], ['pink', 'brown']]
```

And if we just wish to iterate once, then (similar to Martijn's - plus playing less with sets):

```
from itertools import count
def unique_plurals(iterable):
    seen = {}
    return [el for el in iterable if next(seen.setdefault(el, count())) == 1]

new = map(unique_plurals, col)
```

This is more flexible in terms of specifying how many occurrences are required, and keeps one `dict` instead of multiple `set`s.

Comment: Nice use of inheritance. According to the comments, order doesn't matter, but I still like this.

Comment: I just wrote this with a classic for-loop. I bow to your genius.

Comment: @Marcin I hadn't noticed order wasn't important - was looking at the example output - not the comments. Anyway, the `OrderedCounter` here is just lifted (minus the repr and reduce) from the end of recipes listed at http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: I understand `OrderedCounter` inherits `Counter` and  `OrderedDict` but I couldn't understand your first trick (I tired) How this is working? Can you give some hint. Thanks!

Comment: I think know I got it `OrderedCounter(el)`returns a *ordered* dict that is both Counter (means key frequency pair). I couldn't understand why you creates a class `OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan it turns out that order wasn't important - so a `Counter` (or other solutions presented) would have sufficed.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `.count()` as it scans through your list *for each element*. Moreover, it'll add items to the output multiple times if they appear 3 or more times in the input.

You'd be better off using a generator function here that only yields items it has seen before, but only once:

```
def unique_plurals(lst):
    seen, seen_twice = set(), set()
    seen_add, seen_twice_add = seen.add, seen_twice.add
    for item in lst:
        if item in seen and item not in seen_twice:
            seen_twice_add(item)
            yield item
            continue
        seen_add(item)

[list(unique_plurals(c)) for c in col]
```

This iterates just *once* through each list (unlike using a `Counter()`).

This method is *far* faster:

```
>>> timeit('[[k for k, v in OrderedCounter(el).iteritems() if v != 1] for el in col]', 'from __main__ import col, OrderedCounter')
52.00807499885559
>>> timeit('[[k for k, v in Counter(el).iteritems() if v != 1] for el in col]', 'from __main__ import col, Counter')
15.766052007675171
>>> timeit('[list(unique_plurals(c)) for c in col]', 'from __main__ import col, unique_plurals')
6.946599006652832
>>> timeit('[list(unique_plurals_dict(c)) for c in col]', 'from __main__ import col, unique_plurals_dict')
6.557853937149048
```

That's about 8 times faster than the `OrderedCounter` method, 2.2 times the `Counter` method.

Jon's one-dictionary-plus-counter method is faster still, though!

However, if you just needed to eliminate values that appear only *once* but keep the rest intact including repeats, then you'd use (borrowing from Jon):

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

def nonunique_plurals(lst):
    seen = defaultdict(count)
    for item in lst:
        cnt = next(seen[item])
        if cnt:
            if cnt == 1:
                # yield twice to make up for skipped first item
                yield item
            yield item
```

This produces:

```
>>> [list(nonunique_plurals(c)) for c in col]
[['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'yellow'], ['pink', 'pink', 'brown', 'brown']]
>>> timeit('[non_uniques(c) for c in col]', 'from __main__ import col, non_uniques')
17.75499200820923
>>> timeit('[list(nonunique_plurals(c)) for c in col]', 'from __main__ import col, unique_plurals')
9.306739091873169
```

That's almost twice the speed of the `Counter()` solution [proposed by FMc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19274474), but it doesn't retain order as precisely:

```
>>> list(nonunique_plurals(['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c']))
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
>>> non_uniques(['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: I suspect the difference would narrow significantly for a larger input.

Comment: @Marcin: Why's that? I think it'll *widen*. The `Counter` keeps updating the count past 2, so the more values there are to count, the more it'll increment the counter, issuing an update.

Comment: @Marcin: That's apart from iterating over the full input list plus the unique values, while mine omits that extra iteration step.

Comment: Because the `Counter` method should only be iterating twice over each list (once to build the `Counter`, once over the `Counter`).

Comment: @Marcin: yes, and my method is iterating over that same input list, then *doesn't iterate again*. *And* the constant cost of the first iteration is lower.

Comment: Okay - I've bitten and gone for a loop once then Martijn :P

Comment: @JonClements: A+ on that one, you beat mine!

Comment: @MartijnPieters `defaultdict(count)` - I like it :P

Comment: In your first function probably you wanted to write `seen_add(item)` instead of `seen.add(item)` after continue? Btw Is there any specify reason that you used `_` name instead of `.` access operator for bounded function.

Comment: @Grijesh: thanks, yes that should have used the local. Local lookups are faster than attribute lookups; in critical loops that can make a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

> my understanding is that the normal for-loop is faster than list comprehension.

Nope.

Your loop is slow because it duplicates operations. For every string in each nested list in `col` it performs a count of the number of instances of that string, so for each `c` in `col`, it performs `len(c)**2` comparisons. That's an `O(NM^2)` squared algorithm. That gets slow quickly.

To make this faster, use better datastructures. Use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Hi Marcin, your solution worked fine. I used collections.Counter and it was 100 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

This addresses your **revised** question: it does make two passes over the inner lists (first to count, then to retrieve) and thus isn't as fast as possible; however, it preserves order and is very readable. As usual, trade-offs abound!

```
from collections import Counter

cols = [
    ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow'],
    ['pink', 'orange', 'brown', 'pink', 'brown'],
]

def non_uniques(vals):
    counts = Counter(vals)
    return [v for v in vals if counts[v] > 1]

non_uniqs = map(non_uniques, cols)

# [
#    ['red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow'],
#    ['pink', 'brown', 'pink', 'brown'],
# ]
```