# How to use numpy functions to make this list

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, list-comprehension

I am trying to speed up this list comprehension, I tried using `numpy.vectorize`, but couldn't make it work. Is it possible to use that function and if so how or is there another way to make this faster? List "a" is  a numpy ndarray (in 2D) so I know that to make it faster u should use numpy functions and not a list comprehension, but couldn't find how to do it using these functions.

```
[[[255,255,255] if y else [0,0,0] for y in row ] for row in a]
```

Comment: What are you using it for? Can it just be broadcast-ed using NumPy? Can you give an example for what value you are using for `list`? Btw you shouldn't use `list` as a variable.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to speed up list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273256/how-to-speed-up-list-comprehension)

Comment: @AviThour Just because it has a similar title doesn't make the question the same. The answer for the linked question would not help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your list will be something like:

```
In [22]: alist = [[0,1,2],[3,0,0]]
```

And the result of your comprehension:

```
In [23]: [[[255,255,255] if y else [0,0,0] for y in row] for row in alist]      
Out[23]: 
[[[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
 [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

To do something similar in `numpy`, make an array (the sublists must all have the same length):

```
In [24]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                  
In [25]: arr                                                                    
Out[25]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 0, 0]])
```

Make a target array - 3d shape:

```
In [27]: res = np.zeros(arr.shape+(3,),int)                                     
In [28]: res                                                                    
Out[28]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

A mask where `y` is not 0:

```
In [29]: mask = arr!=0                                                          
In [30]: mask                                                                   
Out[30]: 
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

This mask will select 3 elements of `res`:

```
In [31]: res[mask]                                                              
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

We can set values with a scalar:

```
In [32]: res[mask] = 255                                                        
In [33]: res                                                                    
Out[33]: 
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

or array:

```
In [34]: res[mask] = [255,255,255]                                              
In [35]: res                                                                    
Out[35]: 
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

Sometimes when setting masked arrays like this we run into broadcasting errors - a mismatch between the target array and the source.

Another approach is to treat the `mask` as a 0/1 indexing array:

```
In [37]: x = np.array([[0,0,0],[255,255,255]])                                  
In [39]: x[mask.astype(int)]                                                    
Out[39]: 
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

If you are starting with lists, the list comprehension approach may be fastest.  While array indexing is fast, converting lists to arrays has a significant overhead.

====

To do this with `np.vectorize` I have use to `signature`, which is slower than regular `vectorize`:

```
In [49]: np.vectorize(lambda y: np.array([255,255,255]) if y else np.array([0,0,
    ...: 0]), signature='()->(n)')(alist)                                       
Out[49]: 
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [11]: np.where(a, np.array([255, 255, 255]), 0)
Out[11]:
array([[255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [255, 255, 255]]
```

An alternative is to first create a full array or zero array, and then update the rows:

```
In [21] res = np.zeros((3, 3))

In [22]: np.where(a == 0, res, 255)
Out[22]:
array([[255., 255., 255.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [255., 255., 255.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying out some more things I found this oneliner, which does the job and is quick too.

```
    np.where(a != 0, 0, 255).repeat(3, 1).reshape(len(a), len(a[0]), 3)
```